# When i tile textures, every other tile on the y axis renders black

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, image

Clearly the texture should be seamless and it's pretty hard to screw up the mapping on a plane (which isn't the problem, I tried giving it thickness)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is the .blend file with just the floor and it's texture

[image]

Comment: I think you don't give enough details, for example how did you unwrap your ground?

Comment: There not much to do when it comes to unwrapping a plane is there?

Comment: what do you mean when you say that you tiled? Is there one mesh for your ground, or several? Please give some more details, I guess it's impossible to help with so few details

Comment: that was bad wording on my part it's a single plane with the texture shown in the UV map and by tiled all i meant was it was repeating, im used to photoshop terms

Comment: so you unwraped your mesh and gave it the texture, then duplicate your object several times, and the problem is that the duplicated objects are black?

Comment: No its just a single plane with the texture, and when rendered, between the repeats in the texture, those black lines appear

Comment: perhaps share the file with only the floor and pack the image so it comes with the file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: it renders just fine for me, might be a bug, I am using blender 2.79.6 Win Also tested in 2.8 and works just fine for me.

Comment: Its working after chaning nothing now but it wasnt earlier today so idk what was wrong but thanks for all your help anyway